# Easiest way to add a month to a java DATE type without using Calendar or Joda?

Tags: java, date, websphere-process-server

I am working in an integrated environment (IBM Process Server) and I am not able to import anything, can only use standard java functionality.

How can I add x number of months to a given date?

Comment: Why without using `Calendar`? It's part of Java SE.

Comment: How is `java.util.Calendar` not standard?

Comment: I cannot issue any import statements.

Comment: So you can't `import java.util.Date` either?

Comment: If you can't import `java.util.Date`, then the whole thing is kind of pointless, is it not?

Comment: Then how do you work with `java.util.Date` if you can't import it?

Comment: There is no need to import date, it is already imported by default. Just not calendar.

Comment: I see this is a homework assignment. Please tag it as such

Comment: Can you read the lines before any "class" in your <whatever>.java file, then check if there is a `import java.util.Date;` or `import java.util.*`? Or else post the full class name of this `Date` class (my.package.Date).

Comment: @ewok this is not... this is my assignment at work. I am just new to java.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza There isn't anything...this is a code snipped which gets integrated "magically" into IBM process server.

Comment: @antonpug if that is the case, see my answer below.  However, it seems bizarre that your work would not permit you to add an import line

Comment: @antonpug you should have posted that from the beginning.

Comment: @Ewok...it's not work...it's the stupidity of IBM process server

Comment: @antonpug I see that now.  As Luiggi pointed out, that would have been useful to know from the beginning.  regardless, my answer should be what you are looking for.  **make sure you see the note**

Comment: You can add imports to a business process. Access the properties for the business process, by right-clicking on the green start circle and selecting "show in->properties view". Inside the properties view, find the "java imports" tab. Enter your imports there, e.g. "import java.util.Calendar;"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that you have Date imported by default, you can add a number of months to the date object by the following:

```
public void addMonths(Date date, int numMonths){
    date.setMonth((date.getMonth() - 1 + numMonths) % 12 + 1);
}
```

**NOTE**

You can use external classes from Java SE by using their full package name.  i.e., even if you cannot add `import java.util.Calendar;` to the top of you `.java` file, you can still create a calendar object by executing `java.util.Calendar cal = java.util.Calendar.getInstance();`

Comment: The Date.setMonth(int) method is deprecated almost since Java began. Consider whether there will be any disadvantage to using deprecated methods (even if it's only seeing a stream of warnings generated by your compiler).

Comment: @user1515834 true.  Most of `java.util.Date` was deprecated and replaced by `java.util.Calendar`, but as we've seen, using `java.util.Calendar` seems to be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

@ewok's answer does not work always when going past the year end, only with **`numMonths` set to values lower or equal to the months until next January**:

SSCCE:

```
public static  void main(String[] args) {
  for(int i=0;i<10; i++) {
    Date date = new Date();
    Date updated = (Date)date.clone();
    addMonths(updated, i);
    System.out.println(" original: " + date+  " adding " +i+ " months: " + updated);
  }
}

public static void addMonths(Date date, int numMonths){
  date.setMonth((date.getMonth() - 1 + numMonths) % 12 + 1);
}
```

Output:

```
original: Sat Aug 24 14:02:17 CEST 2013 adding 0 months: Sat Aug 24 14:02:17 CEST 2013
original: Sat Aug 24 14:02:17 CEST 2013 adding 1 months: Tue Sep 24 14:02:17 CEST 2013
original: Sat Aug 24 14:02:17 CEST 2013 adding 2 months: Thu Oct 24 14:02:17 CEST 2013
original: Sat Aug 24 14:02:17 CEST 2013 adding 3 months: Sun Nov 24 14:02:17 CET 2013
original: Sat Aug 24 14:02:17 CEST 2013 adding 4 months: Tue Dec 24 14:02:17 CET 2013
original: Sat Aug 24 14:02:17 CEST 2013 adding 5 months: Fri Jan 24 14:02:17 CET 2014
original: Sat Aug 24 14:02:17 CEST 2013 adding 6 months: Sun Feb 24 14:02:17 CET 2013
original: Sat Aug 24 14:02:17 CEST 2013 adding 7 months: Sun Mar 24 14:02:17 CET 2013
original: Sat Aug 24 14:02:17 CEST 2013 adding 8 months: Wed Apr 24 14:02:17 CEST 2013
original: Sat Aug 24 14:02:17 CEST 2013 adding 9 months: Fri May 24 14:02:17 CEST 2013
```

**Notice** the February, March, etc dates are back in 2013! The code is flawed because of the strange arithmetics... setMonth handles values > 12 too...

Corrected (though still using the deprecated method...):

```
      date.setMonth((date.getMonth() + numMonths) );
```

Output:

```
original: Sat Aug 24 14:13:09 CEST 2013 adding 0 months: Sat Aug 24 14:13:09 CEST 2013
original: Sat Aug 24 14:13:09 CEST 2013 adding 1 months: Tue Sep 24 14:13:09 CEST 2013
original: Sat Aug 24 14:13:09 CEST 2013 adding 2 months: Thu Oct 24 14:13:09 CEST 2013
original: Sat Aug 24 14:13:09 CEST 2013 adding 3 months: Sun Nov 24 14:13:09 CET 2013
original: Sat Aug 24 14:13:09 CEST 2013 adding 4 months: Tue Dec 24 14:13:09 CET 2013
original: Sat Aug 24 14:13:09 CEST 2013 adding 5 months: Fri Jan 24 14:13:09 CET 2014
original: Sat Aug 24 14:13:09 CEST 2013 adding 6 months: Mon Feb 24 14:13:09 CET 2014
original: Sat Aug 24 14:13:09 CEST 2013 adding 7 months: Mon Mar 24 14:13:09 CET 2014
original: Sat Aug 24 14:13:09 CEST 2013 adding 8 months: Thu Apr 24 14:13:09 CEST 2014
original: Sat Aug 24 14:13:09 CEST 2013 adding 9 months: Sat May 24 14:13:09 CEST 2014
```

**Things to consider**

- Last days of months, from the Java doc of setMonth():

  > Sets the month of this date to the specified value. This Date object is modified so that it represents a point in time within the specified month, with the year, date, hour, minute, and second the same as before, as interpreted in the local time zone. **If the date was October 31, for example, and the month is set to June, then the new date will be treated as if it were on July 1, because June has only 30 days.**
- Still deprecated - Solving the problem properly would be overly time consuming however (exceptional cases, leap days, leap seconds, whatever), not to mention total reinvention of the wheel... Maybe trimming Calendar to the bare minimum, and pasting it into the code would solve it - but even that is not worth the hassle...
- Should definitely try the second approach what @ewok suggested, the fully qualified classname thing.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to implement without calendar use @ewok suggestion if working with deprecated method a problem then use the following code:

```
SimpleDateFormat dt1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");  //Date format
    SimpleDateFormat dt = new SimpleDateFormat("MM");
    Date date = dt1.parse("2013-12-31");
    int dm=0;
    int m = Integer.parseInt(dt.format(date));
    switch(m){
        case 2:
            m = 27;
        break;
        case 4:
        case 6:
        case 9:
        case 11:
            m = 29;
        break;
        default:
            m = 30;
        break;
    }// Closing switch block
    long month = Math.round(1000*60*60*24.25*m);
    long oneMonthTime =  date.getTime()+month;
    System.out.println(dt1.format(oneMonthTime));
```

This code is not for leap year.
I know its non perfect one but still working code.

Answer (score -1):

## tl;dr

```
myJavaUtilDate.toInstant()                      // Convert troublesome legacy `java.util.Date` object to a modern java.time object, `Instant`.
    .atZone( ZoneId.of( "Pacific/Auckland" ) )  // Adjust that `Instant` object from UTC to a particular time zone thereby instantiating a `ZonedDateTime` object, to determine dates.
    .plus( Period.ofMonths( 6 ) )               // Add six months represented by a `Period` to instantiate another `ZonedDateTime` object.
```

## java.time

The *java.time* classes are built into Java 8, Java 9, and later. These supplant the troublesome old date-time classes such as `Date` and `Calendar`.

If you must inter-operate with an existing `Date` object, convert to java.time. The equivalent is `Instant`. The [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) (up to nine (9) digits of a decimal fraction).  Convert using new methods added to the old classes.

```
Instant instant = myJavaUtilDate.toInstant() ;
```

An `Instant` is a moment in UTC. Adding six months requires a date. A time zone is crucial in determining a date. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone. For example, a few minutes after midnight in [Paris France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/Paris) is a new day while still “yesterday” in [Montréal Québec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal).

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter pseudo-zones such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;
```

Adjust your `Instant` into that time zone, applying a `ZoneId` to get a `ZonedDateTime` object.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z ) ;
```

Define six months as a `Period`.

```
Period p = Period.ofMonths( 6 ) ;
```

Add that `Period` object to generate a new `ZonedDateTime` object.

```
ZonedDateTime later = zdt.plus( p ) ;
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/KU4Yl6).

> instant.toString(): 2018-01-31T06:26:34.580Z
>
> zdt.toString(): 2018-01-31T01:26:34.580-05:00[America/Montreal]
>
> p.toString(): P6M
>
> later.toString()2018-07-31T01:26:34.580-04:00[America/Montreal]

If you need to get back to a value in UTC, extract a `Instant`.

```
Instant instant = later.toInstant() ;
```

If you need a `Date`, convert. But try to avoid this class if possible.

```
Date d = Date.from( instant ) ;
```

If you have date-only value without time-of-day, use `LocalDate`. The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 2018 , Month.JANUARY , 23 ) ;  // January 23, 2018.
LocalDate later = ld.plusMonths( 6 ) ;
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Comment: Dear Down-voter, please leave a criticism along with your vote.